# add textbox row below header gridview to use as filter

Tags: filter, datagridview

I have seen at times, datagridviews using an extra cell placed right under the Header of the column, as a filter for the values in the specific column.
I know it is possible to do so through a templatefield in ASP but I need to alter a desktop application using a DataGridView to display the data.
Does anyone know how to add a filter row to the grid in a vb net desktop application?
If I place a textbox right below the header row of the grid, I will hide the first row of data and I want to avoid this; if I place a textbox somewhere on the form, it looks pretty tacky.
Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: If you want jump down this rabbit hole by setting the `DataGridView`s first row as a user “search” row… get ready for a considerable amount of work. One issue is going to be how to keep the “search” row ALWAYS on the top row. You will inevitably encounter other issues if you try to do as you describe "inside" the `DataGridView`. So my question to you would be… what have you tried? In addition, is it possible for you to make the text boxes “not-tacky” looking? Using the “search” text boxes external of the grid will be much easier to implement.

Comment: I have re-looked at my grid and I think (obviously) I can come up with a subset of text boxes only for the columns I'm interested in filtering.
I know I saw it done but right now I can't remember if it was a desktop app or a webpage.
More later...